# Why is Silverlight 5 Assembly.LoadFrom declared internal?

Tags: c#, silverlight

- Long drawn out sigh * Again like Alice, I find myself tumbling down the rabbit hole once more. AKA the Microsoft decision makers.

I should mention I never installed the SL5 beta. I waited until well after the actual release. Before installing the official v5 release.

So using Telerik JustDecompile (replacement for .NET Reflector) I loaded up the fallowing SL assemblies and just for thoroughness I threw in WP7 as well ...

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v3.0\mscorlib.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v4.0\mscorlib.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Silverlight\5.0.61118.0\mscorlib.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v4.0\Profile\WindowsPhone\mscorlib.dll
```

In WP7 System.Reflection.Assembly contains the fallowing methods ...

```
public static Assembly Load(string assemblyString);
public static Assembly LoadFrom(string assemblyFile);
```

In SL3 System.Reflection.Assembly contains the fallowing methods ...

```
public static Assembly Load(string assemblyString);
public static Assembly Load(byte[] rawAssembly);
public static Assembly Load(byte[] rawAssembly, byte[] rawSymbolStore);
public static Assembly LoadFrom(string assemblyFile);
```

In SL4 System.Reflection.Assembly contains the fallowing methods ...

```
public static Assembly Load(string assemblyString);
public static Assembly Load(byte[] rawAssembly);
public static Assembly Load(byte[] rawAssembly, byte[] rawSymbolStore);
public static Assembly LoadFrom(string assemblyFile);
```

In SL5 System.Reflection.Assembly contains the fallowing methods ...

```
public static Assembly Load(string assemblyString);
internal static Assembly Load(byte[] rawAssembly);
internal static Assembly Load(byte[] rawAssembly, byte[] rawSymbolStore);
internal static Assembly LoadFrom(string assemblyFile);
```

Now I have to ask just what in the heck is going on?!?  Load and LoadFrom in SL5 has changed to internal! Why? I ask because in various places though out my code I make use of LoadFrom to load an assembly from disk. My code was originally written for XNA 3, then ported to XNA 4 then to SL4 but as I am updating to SL5 LoadFrom is no longer available. Why would a feature be made available for the last 2 or more versions only to have it *hidden* in SL5 ?

I've posted this question in the Silverlight forums with no response and the SL5 what's new and what's changed docs don't seem to mention it.

Comment: I'm not sure why the scope changed.  My best guess would be that they used to be marked SecurityCritical then in later updates were just made internal.  If you want to load an assembly into memory try the [AssemblyPart.Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.assemblypart.load%28VS.95%29.aspx) method.

Comment: Hmm, [FriendAccessAllowed], that's novel.  How you get friendly is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

From the [non-silverlight MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1009fa28.aspx)

> The LoadFrom method has the following disadvantages. Consider using
>   Load instead.
>
> If an assembly with the same identity is already loaded, LoadFrom
>   returns the loaded assembly even if a different path was specified.
>
> If an assembly is loaded with LoadFrom, and later an assembly in the
>   load context attempts to load same the assembly by display name, the
>   load attempt fails. This can occur when an assembly is de-serialized.
>
> If an assembly is loaded with LoadFrom, and the probing path includes
>   an assembly with the same identity but a different location, an
>   InvalidCastException, MissingMethodException, or other unexpected
>   behavior can occur.
>
> LoadFrom demands FileIOPermissionAccess.Read and
>   FileIOPermissionAccess.PathDiscovery, or WebPermission, on the
>   specified path.
>
> If a native image exists for assemblyFile, it is not used. The
>   assembly cannot be loaded as domain neutral.
>
> In the .NET Framework version 1.0 and 1.1, policy is not applied.

It's been a good practice for some time not to use LoadFrom.  I suspect this is just the formalisation of that practice.